# Can someone Explain why a number higher and lower will calculate but my actual number wont?

Tags: c#, stopwatch, ulong

So, this console app just prints if a number is prime or not, works great for almost every number, but when the assignment is asked to time test the function with two hardcoded numbers (7389274937501454911 and 9389274937501454911) these numbers will not print out anything BUT +1 or -1 to both numbers WILL print out.

```
using System;

namespace IsPrime
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            string isPlaying = "y";
            bool isPrime;

            while(isPlaying == "y")
            {
                var timer = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew ();
                isPrime = isPrimeNum(9389274937501454911);
                if (isPrime)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(9389274937501454911 + " is Prime");
                }
                else 
                    Console.WriteLine(9389274937501454911 + " is not prime");

                isPrime = isPrimeNum(7389274937501454911);
                if (isPrime)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(7389274937501454911 + " is Prime");
                }
                else 
                    Console.WriteLine(7389274937501454911 + " is not prime");
                timer.Stop ();
                var time = timer.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                Console.WriteLine("Elasped Time: " + time + "\n");

                Console.WriteLine("Do you want to play again?: y / n");
                isPlaying = Console.ReadLine ();

            }
        }

        static bool isPrimeNum(ulong n)
        {
            if (n == 1 || n == 2)
                return true;

            if (n % 2 == 0)
                return false;

            for(ulong i = 3; i < n; i = i + 2) 
            {
                if (n % i == 0)
                    return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You mean it prints `-1` and `+1` to the console?

Comment: it will print if the number is prime or not so a bool; true or false

Comment: but wont print out anything at all, for those two hardcoded numbers

Comment: What do you mean? You said this in your question: `these numbers will not print out anything BUT +1 or -1 to both numbers WILL print out.`

Comment: i know i see i worded the question wrong, i meant if i add +1 or -1 to those hardcoded numbers it will print out. but those specific numbers will not print.

Comment: In the IsPrime put a message after the for loop that it has completed. Maybe its not printing anything because it is still processing.

Comment: you know what, your right. i didnt think this process would take longer a few seconds

Comment: @ConnorOwens I have reformed your code, try now

Answer (score 0):

## I have reformed your code, try now

```
using System;

namespace IsPrime
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            string isPlaying = "y";
            bool isPrime;

            while(isPlaying == "y")
            {
                var timer = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew ();
                isPrime = IsPrime(9389274937501454911);
                if (isPrime)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(9389274937501454911 + " is Prime");
                }
                else 
                    Console.WriteLine(9389274937501454911 + " is not prime");

                isPrime = IsPrime(7389274937501454911);
                if (isPrime)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(7389274937501454911 + " is Prime");
                }
                else 
                    Console.WriteLine(7389274937501454911 + " is not prime");
                timer.Stop ();
                var time = timer.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                Console.WriteLine("Elasped Time: " + time + "\n");

                Console.WriteLine("Do you want to play again?: y / n");
                isPlaying = Console.ReadLine ();

            }
        }

        public static bool IsPrime(ulong number)
        {
            if (number == 1) return false;
            if (number == 2) return true;
            if (number % 2 == 0) return false;

           //This returns the whole number greater than or equal to the specified number, and in this case
           //In this case, I take the square root, obvious to divide in half, so the variable i increases twice, since I'm working with the biggest number and divided in half
            var boundary = (ulong)Math.Floor(Math.Sqrt(number));

            for (ulong i = 3; i <= boundary; i += 2)
            {
                if (number % i == 0) return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This works Great and really shortens the processing time.

Comment: @ConnorOwens In Stack Overflow we are at your service ;-)

Comment: now does the i += 2 in the loop matter as long as its incremented by a even number? so say 4? or 40? or 10000? I'm just trying to really understand the process.

Comment: @Héctor Manuel Martinez Durán, A proper answer should have explanation of what you have done, this community aims to teach people coding, by giving him editing code without telling its concept or improvement will make op to copy paste code and he wont get why his code  was getting error

Comment: @Agent_Orange my original code wasn't giving errors but wasn't optimized. This is optimized by the sqrt of the value passed which i stupidly forgot. The i+=2 makes complete sense to me as that was in my original code. but im just curious as why a i += 10000 makes the process even faster and still returns the correct primes.

Comment: @Agent_Orange There you have the explanation
I did not think it necessary to explain since it is his code, and I only added a couple of lines
By the way, thanks for the negative feedback, it does not affect me since you said it yourself, reputation is not important, but answers questions

Comment: @Héctor Manuel Martinez Durán, hmm i dont think it was a negative feedback but i am just giving tip to include explaination to answer, cuz i have got my downvotes for doing same.

Comment: @Agent_Orange Well, I've edited my post and explained what I did, take a look

Comment: @Héctor Manuel Martinez Durán, ya i upvoted it , you didnt need to insert my name there :v , but anyways nice work *Thumbs UP*

Comment: @ConnorOwens `i+=1000` "makes the process faster" because it skips over 1000 values to test. It's not correct though. It may appear to work for your two particular primes but in the general case you need to check every value. You add two (instead of one) to skip processing of the even numbers since they can't be prime by definition. Try adding 1000 or 100 or even 4 and then call your function for a smaller value. Try `IsPrime(25)`.  True?? Oops!